# How do I display an onclick event to the browser?

Tags: javascript, onclick

This is the object of my assignment:

Design a page that has a grid of 20 of your friends faces. Have a “Start” button that kicks off a 20 second timer and then count the number of faces a player can click in that time.

Once the 20 seconds is up, give the user an alert with how many faces they clicked. You cannot count the same face being clicked multiple times.

---

I have figured out how to create an increment counter function.  This function allows the player to click an image and the counter will increase by one every time an image is clicked.

This the function I created.

```
var counter=0;
 function incrementCounter() {
  counter+=1;
  console.log(counter);
}
```

Is there something I can add to the function that will allow the counter to be displayed in a box, every time an image is clicked?  The incrementation can be viewed in the console(using Chrome Dev Tools), however I don't know how to make it appear on the browser.

Comment: Create a DIV and use innerHTML to populate it with whatever you want.

Comment: simple/not-the-proper-answer: `document.writeln(counter)`. instead of logging the value, write it into the document's DOM somewhere.

Comment: `document.writeln` will not have the desired effect, as it will destroy the page when not used during page load, but in a click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your incrementCounter function.

```
document.getElementById("counter-div").innerHTML = counter;
```

Note: Your incrementCounter function doesn't seem to account for a duplicate face being clicked, as that is part of your assignment I figured I'd point it out.

Comment: Thanks David.  It's a little more complex than this however I'd like to thank you for responding.

Comment: More complex how?  This and Kyle's answer do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Well, I will try this again.   Thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick="incrementCounter()">Click</button>
<div id="display"><div>

var counter=0;
function incrementCounter() {
  counter+=1;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = counter;
}
```

here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/va12d766/

Comment: Kyle, thank you for your response.   However  I need to have a display on the browser that will count the number of clicks when the player clicks on an image and not a button.   If you have more insights that would be helpful.

Comment: Not a problem - I used the <button> tag for clarity but you can simply take the onClick="incrementCounter()" and add that to just about any element and it will still work.  For example:  <img onClick="incrementCounter()" src="path/to/picture.jpg" width="100" height="100" />.  make sense?

Comment: Kyle, let me give this a go.  I'll post something should I have concerns.  Thank you.